# How to make regex validator in ASP.NET to stop insertion of data?

Tags: asp.net, regex

I have a grid view in ASP.NET, one of the column of the grid is time(hh:mm).  I have used validators for the field.  They look like this

```
 <FooterTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="st_timef" runat="server"/>
             <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="stRegularExpressionValidator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="HH:MM!"
                            ValidationExpression="/(?:[01]?\d|2[0-3]):(?:[0-5]\d)$/" ControlToValidate="st_timef" />
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="stValidator" runat="server"  ControlToValidate="st_timef" Text="*" ValidationGroup="validaiton"/>
        </FooterTemplate>
```

The validators work,but I have a problem with the regex validator,

Although it shows a error on wrong input format,but it still allows me to press the button which updates the data,(which is not the case of normal validator).

I need the validator to stop running my update function ones it shows a error in validation.

Comment: yeah did that working fine now ty, if possible can I also tell me how to make the error disappear once the correct format is inserted?

Answer (score 0):

You must have to set the *common* validation group name of `ValidationGroup` property for `TextBox`, `Button` and `RegularExpression` validator.

> how to make the error disappear once the correct format is inserted?

Set error description to the `Text` property of validation control (Set empty string to ErrorMessage property).